# Optimise javascript canvas for mass-drawing of tiny objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, optimization, drawimage

I've been working on a game which requires thousands of very small images (20^20 px) to be rendered and rotated each frame. A sample snippet is provided.

I've used every trick I know to speed it up to increase frame rates but I suspect there are other things I can do to optimise this.

Current optimisations include:

- Replacing save/restore with explicit transformations
- Avoiding scale/size-transformations
- Being explicit about destination sizes rather than letting the browser guess
- requestAnimationFrame rather than set-interval

Tried but not present in example:

- Rendering objects in batches to other offscreen canvases then compiling later (reduced performance)
- Avoiding floating point locations (required due to placement precision)
- Not using alpha on main canvas (not shown in snippet due to SO snippet rendering)

```js
//initial canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = 800; 
    canvas.height = 800;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//create an image (I) to render
let myImage = new OffscreenCanvas(10,10);
let myImageCtx = myImage.getContext('2d');
myImageCtx.fillRect(0,2.5,10,5);
myImageCtx.fillRect(0,0,2.5,10);
myImageCtx.fillRect(7.5,0,2.5,10);


//animation 
let animation = requestAnimationFrame(frame);

//fill an initial array of [n] object positions and angles
let myObjects = [];
for (let i = 0; i <1500; i++){
  myObjects.push({
      x : Math.floor(Math.random() * 800),
      y : Math.floor(Math.random() * 800),
      angle : Math.floor(Math.random() * 360),
   });
}

//render a specific frame 
function frame(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  //draw each object and update its position
  for (let i = 0, l = myObjects.length; i<l;i++){
    drawImageNoReset(ctx, myImage, myObjects[i].x, myObjects[i].y, myObjects[i].angle);
    myObjects[i].x += 1; if (myObjects[i].x > 800) {myObjects[i].x = 0}
    myObjects[i].y += .5; if (myObjects[i].y > 800) {myObjects[i].y = 0}   
    myObjects[i].angle += .01; if (myObjects[i].angle > 360) {myObjects[i].angle = 0}   
    
  }
  //reset the transform and call next frame
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

//fastest transform draw method - no transform reset
function drawImageNoReset(myCtx, image, x, y, rotation) {
    myCtx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
    myCtx.rotate(rotation);
    myCtx.drawImage(image, 0,0,image.width, image.height,-image.width / 2, -image.height / 2, image.width, image.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas name = "canvas" id = "canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very close to the max throughput using the 2D API and a single thread, however there are some minor points that can improve performance.

## WebGL2

First though, if you are after the best performance possible using javascript you must use WebGL

With WebGL2 you can draw 8 or more times as many 2D sprites than with the 2D API and have a larger range of FX (eg color, shadow, bump, single call smart tile maps...)

WebGL is VERY worth the effort

### Performance related points

- `globalAlpha` is applied every `drawImage` call, values other than 1 do not affect performance.
- Avoid the call to `rotate` The two math calls (including a scale) are a tiny bit quicker than the `rotate`. eg `ax = Math..cos(rot) * scale; ay = Math.sin(rot) * scale; ctx.setTransform(ax,ay,-ay,ax,x,y)`
- Rather than use many images, put all the images in a single image (sprite sheet). Not applicable in this case
- Don`t litter the global scope. Keep object close as possible to functions scope and pass object by reference. Access to global scoped variable is MUCH slower the local scoped variables.

  Best to use modules as they hove their own local scope
- Use radians. Converting angles to deg and back is a waste of processing time. Learn to use radians `Math.PI * 2 === 360`  `Math.PI === 180` and so on
- For positive integers don't use `Math.floor` use a bit-wise operator as they automatically convert Doubles to Int32 eg `Math.floor(Math.random() * 800)` is faster as `Math.random() * 800 | 0`  ( `|` is OR )

  Be aware of the Number type in use. Converting to an integer will cost cycles if every time you use it you convert it back to double.
- Always Pre-calculate when ever possible. Eg each time you render an image you negate and divide both the width and height. These values can be pre calculated.
- Avoid array lookup (indexing). Indexing an object in an array is slower than direct reference. Eg the main loop indexes `myObject` 11 times. Use a `for of` loop so there is only one array lookup per iteration and the counter is a more performant internal counter. (See example)
- Though there is a performance penalty for this, if you separate update and render loops on slower rendering devices you will gain performance, by updating game state twice for every rendered frame. eg Slow render device drops to 30FPS and game slows to half speed, if you detect this update state twice, and render once. The game will still present at 30FPS but still play and normal speed (and may even save the occasional drooped frame as you have halved the rendering load)

  Do not be tempted to use delta time, there are some negative performance overheads (Forces doubles for many values that can be Ints) and will actually reduce animation quality.
- When ever possible avoid conditional branching, or use the more performant alternatives. EG in your example you loop object across boundaries using if statements. This can be done using the remainder operator `%` (see example)

  You check `rotation > 360`. This is not needed as rotation is cyclic A value of 360 is the same as 44444160. (`Math.PI * 2` is same rotation as `Math.PI * 246912`)

### Non performance point.

Each animation call you are preparing a frame for the next (upcoming) display refresh. In your code you are displaying the game state then updating. That means your game state is one frame ahead of what the client sees. Always update state, then display.

### Example

This example has added some additional load to the objects

- can got in any direction
- have individual speeds and rotations
- don`t blink in and out at edges.

The example includes a utility that attempts to balance the frame rate by varying the number of objects.

Every 15 frames the (work) load is updated. Eventually it will reach a stable rate.

DON`T NOT gauge the performance by running this snippet, SO snippets sits under all the code that runs the page, the code is also modified and monitored (to protect against infinite loops). The code you see is not the code that runs in the snippet. Just moving the mouse can cause dozens of dropped frames in the SO snippet

For accurate results copy the code and run it alone on a page (remove any extensions that may be on the browser while testing)

Use this or similar to regularly test your code and help you gain experience in knowing what is good and bad for performance.

#### Meaning of rate text.

- **1** +/- Number Objects added or removed for next period
- **2** Total number of objects rendered per frame during previous period
- **3** Number Running mean of render time in ms (this is not frame rate)
- **4** Number FPS is best mean frame rate.
- **5** Number Frames dropped during period. A dropped frame is the length of the reported frame rate. I.E. `"30fps 5dropped"` the five drop frames are at 30fps, the total time of dropped frames is `5 * (1000 / 30)`

```js
const IMAGE_SIZE = 10;
const IMAGE_DIAGONAL = (IMAGE_SIZE ** 2 * 2) ** 0.5 / 2;
const DISPLAY_WIDTH = 800;
const DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 800;
const DISPLAY_OFFSET_WIDTH = DISPLAY_WIDTH + IMAGE_DIAGONAL * 2;
const DISPLAY_OFFSET_HEIGHT = DISPLAY_HEIGHT + IMAGE_DIAGONAL * 2;
const PERFORMANCE_SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 15;  // rendered frames
const INIT_OBJ_COUNT = 500;
const MAX_CPU_COST = 8; // in ms
const MAX_ADD_OBJ = 10;
const MAX_REMOVE_OBJ = 5;

canvas.width = DISPLAY_WIDTH; 
canvas.height = DISPLAY_HEIGHT;
requestAnimationFrame(start);

function createImage() {
    const image = new OffscreenCanvas(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE);
    const ctx = image.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect(0, IMAGE_SIZE / 4, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE / 2);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, IMAGE_SIZE / 4, IMAGE_SIZE);
    ctx.fillRect(IMAGE_SIZE * (3/4), 0, IMAGE_SIZE / 4, IMAGE_SIZE);
    image.neg_half_width = -IMAGE_SIZE / 2;  // snake case to ensure future proof (no name clash)
    image.neg_half_height = -IMAGE_SIZE / 2; // use of Image API
    return image;
}
function createObject() {
    return {
         x : Math.random() * DISPLAY_WIDTH,
         y : Math.random() * DISPLAY_HEIGHT,
         r : Math.random() * Math.PI * 2,
         dx: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2,
         dy: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2,
         dr: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.1,
    };
}
function createObjects() {
    const objects = [];
    var i = INIT_OBJ_COUNT;
    while (i--) { objects.push(createObject()) }
    return objects;
}
function update(objects){
    for (const obj of objects) {
        obj.x = ((obj.x + DISPLAY_OFFSET_WIDTH + obj.dx) % DISPLAY_OFFSET_WIDTH);
        obj.y = ((obj.y + DISPLAY_OFFSET_HEIGHT + obj.dy) % DISPLAY_OFFSET_HEIGHT);
        obj.r += obj.dr;       
    }
}
function render(ctx, img, objects){
    for (const obj of objects) { drawImage(ctx, img, obj) }
}
function drawImage(ctx, image, {x, y, r}) {
    const ax = Math.cos(r), ay = Math.sin(r);
    ctx.setTransform(ax, ay, -ay, ax, x  - IMAGE_DIAGONAL, y  - IMAGE_DIAGONAL);    
    ctx.drawImage(image, image.neg_half_width, image.neg_half_height);
}
function timing(framesPerTick) {  // creates a running mean frame time
    const samples = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    const sCount = samples.length;
    var samplePos = 0;
    var now = performance.now();
    const maxRate = framesPerTick * (1000 / 60);
    const API = {
        get FPS() {
            var time = performance.now();
            const FPS =  1000 / ((time - now) / framesPerTick);
            const dropped = ((time - now) - maxRate) / (1000 / 60) | 0;
            now = time;
            if (FPS > 30) { return "60fps " + dropped + "dropped" };
            if (FPS > 20) { return "30fps " + (dropped / 2 | 0) + "dropped" };
            if (FPS > 15) { return "20fps " + (dropped / 3 | 0) + "dropped" };
            if (FPS > 10) { return "15fps " + (dropped / 4 | 0) + "dropped" };
            return "Too slow";
        },
        time(time) { samples[(samplePos++) % sCount] = time },
        get mean() { return samples.reduce((total, val) => total += val, 0) / sCount },
    };
    return API;
}
function updateStats(CPUCost, objects) {
    const fps = CPUCost.FPS;
    const mean = CPUCost.mean;            
    const cost = mean / objects.length; // estimate per object CPU cost
    const count =  MAX_CPU_COST / cost | 0;
    const objCount = objects.length;
    var str = "0";
    if (count < objects.length) {
        var remove = Math.min(MAX_REMOVE_OBJ, objects.length - count);
        str = "-" + remove;
        objects.length -= remove;
    } else if (count > objects.length + MAX_ADD_OBJ) {
        let i = MAX_ADD_OBJ;
        while (i--) {
            objects.push(createObject());
        }
        str = "+" + MAX_ADD_OBJ;
    }
    info.textContent = str + ": "  + objCount + " sprites " + mean.toFixed(3) + "ms " + fps;
}

function start() {
    var frameCount = 0;
    const CPUCost = timing(PERFORMANCE_SAMPLE_INTERVAL);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const image = createImage();
    const objects = createObjects();
    function frame(time) {
        frameCount ++;
        const start = performance.now();
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_WIDTH);
        update(objects);
        render(ctx, image, objects);
        requestAnimationFrame(frame);
        CPUCost.time(performance.now() - start);
        if (frameCount % PERFORMANCE_SAMPLE_INTERVAL === 0) {
            updateStats(CPUCost, objects);
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}
```

```css
#info {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   background: #DDD;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<canvas name = "canvas" id = "canvas"></canvas>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed post. There's a lot to work through - I'll take a proper look today and probably come back with a few questions. Just dropping this comment to say thanks and I'll certainly be looking at all your points!

Comment: Didn't yet look at all the points either (the first is probably the one that should be accepted anyway), but regarding "Rather than use many images, put all the images in a single image (sprite sheet)." are you sure about it as a performance boost? (sincere question). I can see the benefits for loading – single request, single decode etc. – but then at drawing I would have thought that doing the cropping everytime, moving the full image everytime etc would actually eat more perfs than having multiple ImageBitmaps readied from that single sprite-sheet.

Comment: Ah and what do you mean by "Do not be tempted to use delta time"? Do you mean they should just do move incrementally in rAF callback without checking how much time elapsed since last frame? I guess you meant "round the values calculated from the delta time".

Comment: @Kaiido Re second comment. Delta time adds a multiply on top of a +/-. Do it for one,  you must do it for all, Most important and you say it yourself *"...time elapsed since last frame"* How does the last frame define when the next frame will present? If last frame was dropped due to GC load it was already late, and using that time for the next frame which more that likely is on time (next Vsync) means it has the state one frame ahead. Thus one dropped frame results in two out of phase presentations. Delta time can not be used to predict when the current frame will be presented.

Comment: @Kaiido There is no *"cropping"* involved, images are rendered via texture coordinates. The coordinates must be set for the whole image or part  Switching which texture is in use requires a new texture binding to be set (in GPU), this is an expensive GPU state change if done many times. On low end machines this can be a killer (Not all GPUs access texture memory the same way)

Comment: The timestamp you have in rAF is the one of the painting frame so you *know* the frame will get painted exactly after everything in these callbacks will have run. I should probably not have said "since last frame", but if you check the time that elapsed since the beginning of the movement, you don't need to worry about how many frames have been lost. Not using a delta time means your movement will last 4 times less time on a 240Hz monitor than on a 60Hz one, and you will be dependent on perfs... probably not what one wants.

Comment: @Kaiido *"painting frame"* ??  if in the rAF callback the first line subtract time arg from now  `performance.now()-time` it is always positive meaning the time stamp is of an earlier now (likely last vsync on chrome). If it was for the upcoming vsync it would be negative . The JS context can not predict when the frame will be presented (How does it know what frame (rAF callback) will do without running it first?). 240fps If  browser with frame limiting disabled, that is non standard client likely wants 4 times speed

Comment: Yes "painting frame" as the one frame of the event loop where the browser determines it has a ["rendering opportunity"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#rendering-opportunity). That timestamp represents the time when the browser starts executing the [update the rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) part of the event loop, so it's normal that the callbacks that are called later in this algo are executed later... I never said it's forecasting anything.

Comment: And no, people with a 240Hz monitor want to see 4 times more frames than if they had a 60Hz monitor, they certainly don't want to see the animation run 4 times faster... And beware, higher refresh rate are becoming more and more common (it seems new iPhones will run at 120Hz), but you'll probably win more contracts to update all your scripts then.

Comment: @Kaiido In what part of my answer did I say ignore frame rate. A good game will determine the frame rate before starting. Delta time in context of per frame updates reduces performance and worse, animation quality.  You say  *"I never said it's forecasting anything."* if so what is the point of *"...  checking how much time elapsed since last frame? "*

Comment: To know where you are in the animation? How do you do that without a delta time?

Comment: @Kaiido *"To know where you are in the animation? "* this is not an animation, this is a game. *"How do you do that without a delta time?"* Do you know what delta time means in context if a game, when to use it and when not to use it. it is use in multi player to ensure closest possible sync across players, It is used on deterministic systems to predict next frame presentation. It is used in simulations to simplify the math. A game is well written, runs at a very stable selected frame rate, the frame counter tells you where you are at and the time tells you when.